# how to calculate what I need for final exam

Tags: statistics, percentages, means

Evaluation: A final mark out of 100 will be calculated as follows:

Clicker Questions: 5%

WeBWorK Assignments: 10%

Midterm Tests (25% of the higher mark + 10% of the lower): 35%

Test 1 – Saturday, February 7, 10:30-11:50 a.m.

Test 2 – Friday, March 13, 6:00-7:20 p.m.

Final Examination (2.5 hours – date and time TBA): 50%

I have a 80% for Webwork, first midterm I got 39%, second one I got a 26%, and thus the only evaluation I have left is the final exam. Does anyone here know what I need to get on the final to atleast pass the course with a 50% average? In addition I have 0 for Clicker Questions.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe it could be good for your final exam to know how to compute that by yourself ;).

Comment: The course is not a mathematical course(its biology) thus my math is not great enough to do this task..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a weighted average. You weight each element with the correct percentage and then divide by $100$ (the total sum of the weights):
$$\text{final vote} = \frac{0 \times 5 + 80 \times 10 + 39 \times 25 + 26 \times 10 + \text{exam} \times 50}{100}.$$

We want $\text{final vote} \geq 50$, and therefore
$$\frac{0 \times 5 + 80 \times 10 + 39 \times 25 + 26 \times 10 + \text{exam} \times 50}{100} \geq 50,$$
which yields
$$2035 + \text{exam} \times 50 > 5000 \implies \text{exam} \times 50 \geq 2965 \implies \text{exam} \geq 59.3.$$

So you have to score *at least* $59.3\%$ in the final exam.